# How would you compare 3 tables to 1 in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

so I have a possibly silly question, but I'm looking for a basic approach or strategy for the following problem.

I have 1 master file and 3 source files, lets call them master, src1, src2, and src3. The master file is SUPPOSED to have the same records as the 3 source files combined, however, the master file has more records than the sum of all 3 sources. My goal is to validate that all records in said src1-3 are inside the master file AND also extract the records from the master that aren't in any 1 of the 3 sources. Additionally, each of the 4 files have different (but similar) headers

I have been able to find the distinct records from src1 (and subsequent sources) and mapped it to the matching records in the master file by using the following :

```
WITH tmp1 AS (
 SELECT src1.*
 FROM src1 as s1
 LEFT JOIN master as mstr
 ON (
  s1.name = mstr.fname
  s1.quant = mstr.qty
  s1.item = mstr.obj
  s1.price = mstr.prc
  s1.age = mstr.time_since_dob
 )
) SELECT DISTINCT primaryKey from tmp1;
```

Using this, I can get a count of distinct matches between the two files that are present in src1 and if that matches the count from `select distinct PK from src1` then I'm in decent shape. Albeit, I know that using the criteria above I could easily get many collision since several records could have the same name, quantity, item, price, etc... But suffice it to say, using the above criteria I can get unique matches since there are no matching ID's between the two tables or anything like that. Additionally, the join criteria for each source is slightly different so I had to do the above 3 separate times and validate each source independently.

Having done the above along with some other analysis, I have been able to validate that each distinct record from src1-3 has at least 1 distinct match in the master file. I'm having issue, however, with the second half of this challenge where I have to select the records from the master file that did NOT have a corresponding match.

How can I select those records from the master file that were not matched? Can I do a simple
`select * from master not in newView1` where newView1 is the combination of the 3 selects for the 3 sources? Again, I'm using different columns for each join condition so putting 3 sources under the same header might be difficult (but worth pursuing?). Another thing worth mentioning is that each file is ~1gb and the master file is ~3gb so time complexity is worth considering.

Thanks for all and any help.

Comment: Are 'files' the same as 'tables'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, using `UNION ALL` to get all matching rows and rows contained only in `src1-3` tables.
Next, getting also rows of the `master` table that is contained only in the `master` table by joining with the `tmp1` table.
Refer to the following query:

```
with tmp1(tbl,name,quant,item,price,age,fname,qty,obj,prc,time_since_dob) as (
select 'src1',s1.*,m.* from src1 s1 left join master1 m on
    s1.name=m.fname and
    s1.quant=m.qty and
    s1.item=m.obj and 
    s1.price=m.prc and
    s1.age=m.time_since_dob
union all
select 'src2',s2.*,m.* from src2 s2 left join master1 m on
    s2.name=m.fname and
    s2.quant=m.qty and
    s2.item=m.obj and 
    s2.price=m.prc and
    s2.age=m.time_since_dob
union all
select 'src3',s3.*,m.* from src3 s3 left join master1 m on
    s3.name=m.fname and
    s3.quant=m.qty and
    s3.item=m.obj and 
    s3.price=m.prc and
    s3.age=m.time_since_dob
)
select 'master',m.fname,m.qty,m.obj,m.prc,m.time_since_dob from master1 m left join tmp1 t on
    m.fname=t.name and
    m.qty=t.quant and
    m.obj=t.item and 
    m.prc=t.price and
    m.time_since_dob=t.age
where t.name is null
union all
select t.tbl,t.name,t.quant,t.item,t.price,t.age from tmp1 t
where t.fname is null
```

[db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3YrQoCKZv5nwk1ZDD72ZPb/0)